# How can I link a specific 500px portfolio in Facebook with thumbnails in the correct order?

Tags: facebook, photo-viewer, 500px

I am sure this is simple and I am just missing something; How can I post a link to a specific 500px portfolio of mine so that the link others see displays the thumbnail images in the correct order or shows the first image in my portfolio.

If I just copy and paste the link to my portfolio, it adds all the images as thumbnails in some random order.

Comment: I don't think this is related to photography. I am not sure it fits with StackOverflow or SuperUser but maybe better than here.

Comment: This has to do with showing my photography portfolio in a social media site. Isn't showing my work an important aspect of photography?

Comment: This seems like a good fit for the Web Applications StackExchange: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Some questions do overlap several sites.  I think this is a good fit here (although it might also be a good fit elsewhere too). As a photographer, I might well want to know how to show images on facebook.  I think that asking how facebook works with images is in the same ballpark as asking how something like Lightroom works to upload to flickr or similar.  I would vote to keep this question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook is sort of a pain to work with for images, IME.  The most reliable way to throw them clues seems to be the use of their open-graph meta tags.  [This post on wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/facebook-sharing-link-is-not-showing-a-thumbnail-of-the-images-within-the-post) is a pretty good place to start.  I'm not positive I'm looking at [the right 500px portfolio](http://jakubsisak.500px.com/#/0) for you (the link in your profile is broken, I believe), but I'm not seeing any OG tags in there.  Even with the use of OG tags, though, I'm not sure there's a way to specify order beyond just ordering the tags (and I'm not sure how well that's respected by FB).

At some point in 2012, I believe 500px is supposed to offer customizable portfolio themes (most likely for "awesome" customers only), but I have a feeling your best bet may be to just wait for them to get the meta tags sorted out themselves.

Comment: didn't realize my link was broken. Fixed now. thanks! I was hoping for a much easier solution then customizing the code on the page. (i think smugmug has it but if i purchase an online solution i think i will go with 500px only because I love the community there.) Basically, currently pasting a link to my portfolio adds i think the thumbnails to all my photos there but i would only like it to display those from the particular portfolio with the newest image being preferably the fist displayed thumbnail.

Comment: Some really nice photos in the portfolio, btw.

Comment: OK. I did not realize I can manually navigate to the photo I want to display on the link.  Not ideal but it will do. Thanks for your answer and for the compliment.